# Create Visual Studio 2008 Add-In with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, add-in

is there a way to create a Visual Studio 2008 Add-In with the Visual Studio 2010?

Our customer still uses VS2008, in our upgrade-progress to VS2010 with TFS2010 it would be nice when we're able to develop this Add-In in VS2010.

Or is an Visual Studio 2010 Add-In backward compatible?

Thanks!

Alex

Answer (score 1):

There are three levels of extensibility in Visual Studio :

Macros,
Add-ins,
VS Packages

I can confirm that VS2008 Add-ins work perfectly well in VS2010 beta2. You just have to edit the .AddIn file and replace "9.0" by "10.0".
best regards

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my question was if VS2010 Add-Ins work in VS2008!

Answer (score 0):

u should go to this path and copy add-ins path into,then work its

Open up Visual Studio > Tools Menu > Options > Environment > Add-In/Macro Security > Add the path for example "C:\VisualStudioPlugins"

then u use this add-ins

saeedPy - best regards